# What is MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am developing an application which doesn't have large requirements for data storage. I am instructed not to use RDBMS tables if possible. Can I use MongoDb for this? What are the main advantages and disadvantages of it?

Comment: The answer to this question is one Google search away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is a "[Document Oriented Database](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=document%2boriented%2bdatabase&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database&ei=R1y6TrCvHoOzrAflu9CiBg&usg=AFQjCNGk6HXlxy3gb2S_Syp4fX4A2Qh5QA)", which stores data in JSON format. It is a handy tool for smaller database requirements. MongoDB supports complex operations like join, indexing much easily and efficently as compared to traditional RDBMSs.

However for larger and complex systems its use is still a matter of discussion. You ll get a good insight of [MOngoDB here](http://www.mongodb.org/)....

A good comparison between RDBMS and MongoDB is given [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=document%2boriented%2bdatabase%2bvs%2brelational%2bdatabase&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEMQFjAD&url=http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/document-oriented-databases-vs-relational-databases&ei=hFy6TsGyM43OrQeIqtnUBg&usg=AFQjCNEIoNHMHbLRBzESDF572q88C_VYwQ)

Comment: I would like to add that MongoDB is a standalone application just like RDBMS. Depending on the needs of your application you may find that an in memory database or other approach (eg Maps, Lists and Sets) may do what you want, with persistence to disk if necessary.